# Sum with multiple tables

Tags: sql

I'm running the query:

```
 Select s.scheme, c.surname, p.policynumber, cp.type, ce.TotalReceived   
    from clients c, schemes s, policies p, commnPremiums cp, CommnEntries ce  
    where c.clientref = p.clientref and   
    s.schemeref = p.schemeref and   
    p.policyref = cp.policyref and   
    cp.CommnPremRef = ce.CommnPremRef and   
    s.schemeref = '164003232' and c.surname = 'Smith'
```

Which returns the following records:

```
scheme surname policynumber type TotalReceived   
AxaElevate Smith XEL123 7 1147.38   
AxaElevate Smith XEL123 7 285.14   
AxaElevate Smith XEL123 7 501.16   
AxaElevate Smith XEL123 1 2688.62   
AxaElevate Smith XEL123 5 149.49   
AxaElevate Smith XEL123 1 94.7   
AxaElevate Smith XEL123 5 163.69   
AxaElevate Smith XEL123 5 166.65
```

I would like to sum the totalReceived by type to produce this:

```
scheme surname policynumber type TotalReceived   
AxaElevate Smith XEL123 7 1933.68   
AxaElevate Smith XEL123 1 2783.32   
AxaElevate Smith XEL123 5 479.83
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use group by and sum:

```
 Select s.scheme, 
c.surname, 
p.policynumber, 
cp.type, 
sum(ce.TotalReceived   )
    from clients c, schemes s, policies p, commnPremiums cp, CommnEntries ce  
    where c.clientref = p.clientref and   
    s.schemeref = p.schemeref and   
    p.policyref = cp.policyref and   
    cp.CommnPremRef = ce.CommnPremRef and   
    s.schemeref = '164003232' and c.surname = 'Smith'
GROUP BY
s.scheme, 
c.surname, 
p.policynumber, 
cp.type
```

Once you use an aggregate function (like sum), you will have to aggregate or group by on each field in your select.

Comment: looks like your and mine answer is same. Should i delete mine?

Comment: Thank you so much, I had 'GROUP BY cp.type' only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do group by and then you can do sum

```
Select s.scheme, c.surname, p.policynumber,  cp.type, 
   sum(ce.TotalReceived)
from clients c, schemes s, policies p, commnPremiums cp, CommnEntries ce  
where c.clientref = p.clientref and   
s.schemeref = p.schemeref and   
p.policyref = cp.policyref and   
cp.CommnPremRef = ce.CommnPremRef and   
s.schemeref = '164003232' and c.surname = 'Smith'
GROUP BY
  s.scheme, 
  c.surname, 
  p.policynumber, 
  cp.type
```